# WSO2 CEP SIDDHI LANGUAGE boolean type

Tags: stream, boolean, wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

Is there an allowed boolean type to be used in siddhi query language when defining streams ?
By looking at the language model of Siddhi versión 310 "https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Language+Model" it looks like there is no support for stream boolean attribute type. They only allow: int, long, double, float, string, time types.

Answer (score 0):

It does support boolean, please use `bool`.